# Ckeditor on rails will paste from the web but not from word

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ms-word, ckeditor

I have ckeditor running on a rails 4 app.  If I copy and paste from a browser, tables, formatting and pictures paste fine. However, If I try to paste from word or adobe, the formatting, pics, tables etc are gone. I get placeholders for the pics.

What I don't understand is why when I paste from word or excel all of the formatting and images gets removed.

Why would ckeditor pass formatting and images copied from a browser but not from an office document. ?

Here is my config.js for ckeditor

```
CKEDITOR.editorConfig = function( config ) {
    config.removeButtons = 'Form,Save,NewPage,Preview,Print,Templates,Maximize,Checkbox,Radio,TextField,Textarea,Select,Button,ImageButton,HiddenField,Flash,Iframe,Smiley,Language';
    config.allowedContent=true;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveFontStyles=false;
    config.pasteFromWordRemoveStyles=false;
    config.clipboard_defaultContentType = 'html';

};
```

Comment: Are you using the Paste button or the Paste from Word button? http://docs.ckeditor.com/#!/guide/dev_howtos_pasting

Comment: I tried both.. When I use the Paste from Word button, the text shows up formatted in the dialog box but when it goes into the body , the formatting is stripped.